# Postgres Backup fails with: pg_dump: could not fsync file: Bad file descriptor

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, postgresql-11

I am running Postgres 11 on Windows 10 and this should be my last backup before moving to Linux:

```
"C:\PostgreSQL\pg11\bin\pg_dump.exe" -U postgres -h localhost -p 5432 --verbose --jobs=4 --format=d --blobs --clean --create --if-exists --compress=0 --dbname="DATABASE_NAME" --file="P:\PG11_dump_20190217"
```

This is the end of the log:

```
...
pg_dump: dumping contents of table "schema.table"
pg_dump: finished item 255955 TABLE DATA table
pg_dump: finished item 255956 TABLE DATA table
pg_dump: pg_dump: dumping contents of table "schema.table"
dumping contents of table "schema.table"
pg_dump: finished item 255953 TABLE DATA table
pg_dump: finished item 255952 TABLE DATA table
pg_dump: could not fsync file "P:\PG11_dump_20190217/291267.dat": Bad file descriptor
pg_dump: could not fsync file "P:\PG11_dump_20190217/293909.dat": Bad file descriptor
pg_dump: could not fsync file "P:\PG11_dump_20190217/294060.dat": Bad file descriptor
pg_dump: could not fsync file "P:\PG11_dump_20190217/295715.dat": Bad file descriptor
pg_dump: could not fsync file "P:\PG11_dump_20190217/296142.dat": Bad file descriptor
```

I searched for the `pg_dump: could not fsync file: Bad file descriptor` error but could not find any help.

Maybe of importance: The database is about 3.6 TB and I am using the PostGIS extension.

**Question:** How to prevent this error or work around it?

**Additional question:** Could I do a file level backup and copy the `data` folder from windows to linux, given an identical Postgres version and both servers stopped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question: How to prevent this error or work around it?

[`fsync`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) ensures that the data is physically written to disk, so that in case of a crash or loss or power a few seconds after the backup, no data is lost in unflushed memory buffers. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work in your case. You may add `--no-sync` to avoid this step, although the errors shown are probably harmless, in the sense that surely they don't affect the contents of the backup. You may also use [sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sysinternals/downloads/sync) as an external program if you're wary of skipping the sync.

> Additional question: Could I do a file level backup and copy the data
>   folder from windows to linux, given an identical Postgres version and
>   both servers stopped?

No. The data files are not portable in general, and especially not across totally different operating systems.

Comment: Thanks, the backup completed without a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Never used postgres on Windows personally, but could this be one of those "confused slashes" situations?

The error message seems a little "conflicted" about which to use:

```
         -v-
--file="P:/PG11_dump_20190217" 

                                -v-                -v-
pg_dump: could not fsync file "P:\PG11_dump_20190217/291267.dat": Bad file descriptor
```

Does it dump work any better with this?

```
         -v-
--file="P:/PG11_dump_20190217"
```

Comment: Not enough space left on the windows computer to test this. If `pg_restore` completes without an issue, I will also not come back to windows. IAC, thanks for your answer.